# How to enable OpenGL 3.X in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, opengl

Previously I'm using OpenGL on Mac via glew 2.1.0 and JUCE5, but it can only access OpenGL 2.1 APIs. I can't believe that my Macbook Air (Intel Graphics) bought on 2018 can only provide this, and I'm tired to maintain two sets of API calls and shaders for 2.1 and 3.X separately. Then I tried to replace all `#include <GL/glew.h>` with `#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>`, then link with OpenGL framework directly. However, the program still failed to compile a `#version 130` shader (it claims not supported).

Here I want to know that:

- Does all recent Apple devices (after 2010) capable for OpenGL 3.0?
- How to turn on OpenGL 3.0 support on MacOS?

Comment: I guess you should share some code how you create your OpenGL context. If not - search for OpenGL `Core Profile` initialization.

Comment: How do you create your window? Do you request any special OpenGL version/profile, if so which one?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the way: I have to enable it on JUCE side. When JUCE's OpenGL context is created, I must explicitly set expected OpenGL version by `setOpenGLVersionRequired( juce::OpenGLContext::openGL3_2 )` before using it.

IMPORTANT: this would still lead failure to a compile to `#version 130` shader, as Apple would strictly deprecate all old features prior to specified API version. A simple workaround is to dynamically prepend a version declaration according to system type, as GLSL 1.3.0 features is mostly included by GLSL 1.5.0.